# What is the purpose of {attrs} parameter in v-slot: activator?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I created a simple `v-dialog` using Vuetify. It uses `v-slot:activator` with destructured  data, namely `{on, attrs }`. While I can understand `on` part then I can't get what's the purpose of `attrs`? If I remove it then dialog still works fine. How it works and what is it for?

Here some basic example from Vuetify docs:

```
<template>
  <div class="text-center">
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      width="500"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn
          color="red lighten-2"
          dark
          v-bind="attrs"
          v-on="on"
        >
          Click Me
        </v-btn>
      </template>

      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="text-h5 grey lighten-2">
          Privacy Policy
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
        </v-card-text>

      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its purpose is to give you set of attributes/props that you can easily bind with `v-bind="attrs"` (using [object binding syntax](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#binding-multiple-properties-using-an-object)) to the component you choose as an activator

In the case of `v-dialog` its content is generated by default implementation of `activatable` mixin and [generates some ARIA attribute](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/f74d44ab17a0cf6143cee8440a49509baf1a4fab/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/activatable/index.ts#L94) but the component using the mixin can override or extend it (as for example [v-menu does](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/860be6b0bff74b6cd81320259879ae9dc5a77f1d/packages/vuetify/src/components/VMenu/VMenu.ts#L287))

Comment: Ok, and what could I pass as `attrs` in this case? I still try to figure out what it could be. I was looking for some example of using `attrs` in real example but none of them use it.

Comment: The Vuetify component (`v-dialog` in this case) **gives you** the attributes (in the form of object) that you might want (depends on the component but it is optional in this case) to "forward" to chosen activator component.